# Android studio reads the wrong name in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Android studio throws error after trying to build project:

```
ERROR: Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.1.0:.
```

This means that in line `'com.google.gms.google-services:4.1.0'` Android Studio reads `'com.google.gms.google-services:4.1.0:'` With `:` at the end of line. Any ideas whats wrong ?

This is part of my gradle file

```
  dependencies {
            classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.1.0'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
            classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
            classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.5.0'

        }
```

Comment: are you added google-services.json in your app folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0` and look at you have!